# Restrict outside access to docker

Tags: iptables, docker

I have some difficulties figuring out how to correctly restrict outside access to docker containers.

So far I was using multiple user-defined bridges and exposed HTTP/HTTPS ports.

For example I had:

```
docker-net-1:
0.0.0.0:9080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9443->443/tcp

docker-net-2:
0.0.0.0:8380->80/tcp
```

I then used a reverse proxy on my docker host to provide outside access via port 443 to the different services using name based virtual hosts and making sure everything goes via https.

To prevent direct access to the exposed ports I used the `DOCKER-USER` chain in iptables.

```
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Now I need to host 2 more applications. They are in separate networks but both expose port 22.

```
0.0.0.0:9022->22/tcp
0.0.0.0:9122->22/tcp
```

The tricky part for me now is that I need different firewall rules for those ports.

### What I tried so far:

1. Proxy

   As it is SSH I do not see how it can be easily done
2. Opening port in DOCKER-USER - 1st attempt

   As per default external access is disabled in my `DOCKER-USER` I added the follwing:

   ```
   -A DOCKER-USER -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9022 -j RETURN
   -A DOCKER-USER -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9122 -j RETURN
   -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j RETURN
   -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP
   ```

   Those first 2 rules however never got any hit.
3. Opening port in DOCKER-USER - 2nd attempt

   When looking at the iptables chains again it became clear that at this point the port is not 9022 but 22.

   ```
   -A DOCKER-USER -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j RETURN
   ```

   which works as expected.
4. Opening port in DOCKER-USER - 3rd attempt

   I thought about using the additional network interfaces or ip subnets created by docker to distinguish between the two different applications, but the names of the network interfaces seem like randomly created and the IP addresses are probably also not a good way of solving the problem as those addresses change like the network names when recreated.

### What now?

What is the best solution here? Ideally I do not want something that breaks when services are restarted, like manipulating existing DOCKER chains or using IPs that change.

Comment: We have the same problem. Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Don't expose ports that you don't want accessible outside. That is what exposing is for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-m conntrack --ctorigdstport 9022` instead `--dport 9022`.

More infornation here: https://serverfault.com/a/933803/335954.